# Java set microphone level

Tags: java, audio, volume, microphone

I followed the Java documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) to get an audio stream from the microphone. But it already overmodulates when I am talking normally. Is there any way to set the micophones volume level?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...
While you cant set the level in Java itself you can set it through the system OS.